# Independence of sample mean and sample variance in binomial distribution

Tags: distributions, binomial-distribution, independence

Let $X\sim\mathrm{Binomial}(n,p)$. We know that $\mathrm{E}[X]=np$ and $\mathrm{Var}[X]=np(1-p)$. Does this imply that the *sample* mean $\bar x$ and the *sample* variance $s^2$ are **dependent** of each other? Or does it just mean that the *population* variance can be written as a function of the *population* mean?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

$\bar x$ and $s^2$ are random variables.  We can work out their joint distribution.  Let's try the simplest possible nontrivial case, that of a sample of size $2$ from a Binomial$(1,p)$ distribution.  There are only four possibilities for that sample, which are hereby tabulated along with their probabilities (computed from the independence of the two sample elements):

```
First value | Second value | Mean | Variance | Probability
          0 |            0 |    0 |        0 | (1-p)^2
          0 |            1 |  1/2 |      1/2 | (1-p)p
          1 |            0 |  1/2 |      1/2 | p(1-p)
          1 |            1 |    1 |        0 | p^2
```

The mean perfectly predicts the variance in this example.  Thus, provided all probabilities are nonzero (that is, $p$ is neither $0$ nor $1$), the sample mean and sample variance are *not* independent.

An interesting question is whether, if in a family of distributions the mean determines the variance, the sample mean and sample variance can be independent.  The answer is yes: take any family of Normal distributions in which the variance depends on the mean such as the set of all Normal$(\mu, \mu^2)$ distributions.  No matter which of these distributions governs the sample, the sample mean and sample variance will be independent, because that's the case for *any* Normal distribution.

This analysis suggests that questions about the structure of a *family of distributions* (which concern $n$, $p$, $\mu$, and so forth) have no bearing on questions of independence of statistics of *samples from any given element of the family.*

Comment: But maybe that's because the normal distribution is a "special" case? I mean, it is known that, for any normal distribution, it is true that the sample mean is independent of the sample variance. But what happens if we are dealing with a distribution that it's not a normal distribution?

Comment: Typically the sample mean and sample variance are not independent.  It makes no difference what family of distributions the distribution might be part of.

Comment: @whuber : Except that with $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ the sample mean and sample variance are independent.

Comment: @Michael Thanks.  I already noted that in the body of the answer.

Comment: @whuber: thanks for the analysis. Could you also please disclose the `R` code? Many thanks.

Comment: @Maximilian No `R` code was created or needed in formulating this answer.

Answer (score 11):

The property that, for an i.i.d. sample,  the sample mean and the sample variance are independent, is a *characterization* of the normal distribution: for no other distribution such a property holds.

See [Patel, J. K., & Read, C. B. (1982). Handbook of the normal distribution](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0824793420), p. 81 in the 1st 1982 edition, in chapter "Characterizations" (may have changed pages in the 2nd edition of 1996).

So for any other distribution, the sample mean and the sample variance are statistically dependent.

The general result regarding the sample mean and the sample variance from an i.i.d. sample of any distribution that has moments up to the 3d, is the following (using the unbiased estimator for the variance):

$$\operatorname{Cov} (\bar X, s^2) = E(\bar X s^2) - E(x)\operatorname{Var}(x) = \frac 1n E[X-E(x)]^3$$

In words, the covariance between the sample mean and the sample variance is equal to the third central moment, divided by $n$. Consequences:

For *any* distribution that has the third central moment equal to zero, the two **are uncorrelated** (although they **remain dependent**, for all distributions except the normal). This of course includes all distributions symmetric about their mean, *but also other distributions that are non-symmetric about their mean but still, have the third central moment equal to zero*, [**see this thread**](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/24853/28746).

Comment: @COOLSerdash Thanks. As mentioned, the hyperlink seems valid. Just search "Handbook of normal distribution Patel Read".

Comment: (+1) I suspected that this might be the case but have never seen a formal statement of this fact. Are there non-normal distributions for which the sample mean and sample variance are uncorrelated?

Comment: @JohnColeman Do you mean "uncorrelated even though not independent"?

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos Yes, of course. If so then it would be an interesting example of when uncorrelated doesn't imply independent. I haven't worked out all of the details, but `U(0,1)` seems to work.

Comment: @JohnColeman A general result exists, I added it in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

An extreme case is $\operatorname{Bernoulli}(p) = \operatorname{Binomial}(1,p).$ Consider a sample of size (capital) $N:$
\begin{align}
Ns^2 = \sum_{k=1}^N (x_k - \overline x)^2 = {} & \left( \sum_k x_k^2 \right) - \left( 2\overline x \sum_i x_k \right) + \left( N\overline x^2 \right) \\[10pt]
= {} & \left( \sum_k x_k \right) - 2\overline x \sum_k x_k + \left( n\overline x^2 \right) \\
& \text{since $x_k = 0$ or $1$, so $x_k^2=x_k$} \\[12pt]
= {} & N\overline x - 2N\overline x^2 + N \overline x^2 \\[10pt]
= {} & N \overline x(1-\overline x), \\[10pt]
\text{so } s^2 = {} & \overline x(1-\overline x).
\end{align}
Thus when (lower-case) $n$ is $1,$ then the sample mean determines the sample variance, so they are far from independent. But the sample variance does not quite fully determine the sample mean, since there are two values of $\overline x$ that yield the same value of $\overline x(1-\overline x).$

When both $np$ and $n(1-p)$ are large, then I expect the sample mean and sample variance would be nearly independent since the distribution is nearly normal.