# Index for the shape of a distribution (necessary or sufficient condition?)

Tags: descriptive-statistics, kurtosis, symmetry

I have a confusion about the main statistical indicators for the shape of a distribution. Let me consider first the Fisher index defined as
$$\rho=\frac{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar x)^3}{\sigma^3},$$ where $\sigma$ is the standard deviation of the statistical distribution and $\bar x$ is the total average.
Is it true that

1. If $\rho>0$ then the distribution is positively asymmetric (it is not true the inverse implication)
2. If the distribution is symmetric then $\rho=0$ (it is not true the reverse implication). There exists a counterexample about the inverse implication?
3. If $\rho<0$ then the distribution is negatively asymmetric (it is not true the inverse implication)

Am I correct?

What about the index for the curtosis of a distribution?
$$\beta=\frac{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar x)^4}{\sigma^4}?$$

1. If $\beta>3$ then the distribution is leptokurtic (it is not true the inverse implication)
2. If $\beta=3$ then the distribution is mesokurtic (it is not true the inverse implication)
3. If $\beta<3$ then the distribution is platikurtic (it is not true the inverse implication)

Could someone tell me if I am correct and clarify my ideas?

Comment: These look tautological to me: $\rho$ *defines* whatever "positively/negatively asymmetric" might mean and $\kappa$ *defines* whatever "lepto/platykurtic" might mean.  As argued extensively elsewhere on this site, such moment-based statistics indicate exceptionally little about a distribution's shape (because they inherently depend on the frequencies of extreme values).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am trying to understand well these things. So $\rho>0$ implies positively asymmetric (by definition), while $\rho<0$ implies negatively asymmetric (by definition).  While $\rho=0$ doesn't imply anything. Is this correct?

Comment: The same happens for the Kurtosis index? This means that $\beta=3$ doesn't imply anything?  If you could suggest some link in this page in which these thinngs are discussed I would be very greatful. I am new in the statistics world and I really want to learn.

Comment: What I am saying is that these statements are not implications; they are *definitions.*  They imply little about the shapes of the distributions (except when they achieve extreme values, such as $\kappa=1$).  It's easy to find a lot of material about skewness and kurtosis here on CV: [search kurtosis shape](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=kurtosis+shape) and [search skewness shape](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=skewness+shape).

Comment: This means that a distribution is said negatively asymptotics if $\rho<0$. Therefore if $\rho<0$ then the distribution is negatively asymptotics. On the other hand if it is a definition means that if a distribution is negatively asymmetric tehn $\rho<0$. Therefore a distribution is negatively asymmetric if and only if $\rho<0$. The same should be true for positive asymetry. It is not clear to me how is it possible that $\rho=0$ doesn't imply symmetry.

Comment: This is because a distribution can be symmetric, negative asymmetric, positive asymmetric but can be also none of the previous options. So can be asymmetric (not positively and not negatively)?

Comment: That's right.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24853 for examples of the latter (asymmetric but with $\rho=0$).

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Sorry! I have another question about the Skweness. I can define the positive/negative asimmetry also trough the Pearson index $a_P=\frac{\bar x-Moda}{\sigma}$? In the sense that I can say that a distribution is positevely (negatively) asymmetric when $a_p>0(<0)$?

Answer (score 0):

While use of skewness and kurtosis as measures of *shape* can be dubious, there are precise visual and mathematical interpretations for both that provide correct insights and information. These regard *tail behavior*, rather than shape.

Skewness:

Let $Z = (X - \mu)/\sigma$. Let $Z_3 = Z^3$. Consider the pdf of $Z_3$, call it $p_3(.)$. The skewness of $X$ is the mean of the distribution of $Z_3$, hence it is the "point of balance" of $p_3$.

Now, place a fulcrum at $0.0$ under the graph of $p_3$. If the skewness of $X$ is $>0$, then the graph "falls to the right" of the fulcrum. Thus, the right tail of $X$ is more extreme, in terms of mass and/or extremity, than the left tail, where extremity refers to amplification by the third power.  A similar definition holds for skewness $<0$.  If skewness is $=0$ it does not imply symmetry, but instead equal leverage of the tails, again as amplified through the third power.

Kurtosis:

Let $Z_4 = Z^4$. Consider the pdf of $Z_4$, call it $p_4(.)$. The kurtosis of $X$ is the mean of the distribution of $Z_4$, hence it is the "point of balance" of $p_4$.

If $X$ has a normal distribution, then this point of balance is exactly 3.0.

So place a fulcrum at 3.0 under the graph of $p_4$.  If the kurtosis is $>3$, then the graph falls to the right, indicating that $X$ has greater tail leverage than the normal distribution. Here, "tail" refers to extremity of the $X$ values as amplified through the fourth power.

Note that kurtosis $>3$ tells you nothing about the shape of the peak, or even about the probability within a standard deviation of the mean: The graph falls the the right, not to the left.

If the kurtosis is $<3$, then the graph "falls to the left," and distribution of $X$ has less tail leverage than the normal distribution. This of course tells you nothing about the shape of the "peak."  (It is certainly not "flat" - the Beta(.5,1) distribution provides a simple counterexample).

If kurtosis $=3$, then the tail leverage of $X$ (as amplified by the fourth power) is the same as that of the normal distribution, but it certainly does not imply that the distribution is normal, or even bell-shaped.